# Android Unable to update correct date when I select December as month from the picker

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-timepicker

I am trying to update system time and date. Setting time works fine as i have system permissions in my app and application is signatured as system app also setting date works fine for Months Jan upto Nov, but when i select December as month it is setting month to Jan. this all is cause of i am adding 1 to month but in a case i dont add 1 it creates problem for every month. if I select Dec it is Showing Nov, if I am selecting Jan it works fine , When I select Feb it again selects Jan, If I select March it selects Feb. every time it is setting one month less than the selected one.

here is my code

```
 private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new     TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
@Override
 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
 mHour   = hourOfDay;
 mMinute = minutes;

 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(mYear, mMonth+1, mDay, mHour, mMinute);

 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Action);
 intent.putExtra("time", c.getTimeInMillis());
 getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
};
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  mYear = arg1;
  mMonth = arg2;
  mDay = arg3;

  mTimePickerDialog.show();
 }
};
```

at the other end

```
long when = intent.getLongExtra("time", -1);

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.i(TAG, "Incoming time: " + when);

    if (when / 1000 < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(when);
    }

    Time time = new Time();


    TvManager tvmng = TvManager.getInstance();
    TimerManager timerMgr = null;
    if(tvmng!=null)
        timerMgr = tvmng.getTimerManager();

    time.set(when);

    try {

        timerMgr.setClkTime(time, true);

    } catch (TvCommonException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: This could be [this android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39692). Where do you get your date / time from?

Comment: I am allowing my user to set the date and time from the time and date picker

Comment: No i am not facing that bug as date picker allowing me to select December and yes my system is running on jellybean.

Comment: At the top of your code, you are passing `mMonth+1` to `c.set()`. Because Calendar counts months from zero, you do not need this. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the code as mentioned below.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
```

remove the +1 you added after the month.
When you set the month in calender than it should be between 0 to 11 when you pass month +1 and your month is 11 then it will be 11+1 =12 and calender consider it as Jan not December.

When you use the date selected for the purpose of showing to user then you have to add month+1 so it will show exact month ,
But when you pass it to calender again for the purpose of storing users selection store it as it is without adding +1 if you added it before then make it month-1 and then add to calender object.
It should work as you expected.

Also look at my solution to over come the issue.

to get formatted date to display user

```
 public static String getDate(Calendar calendar){
    String formattedDate;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
    formattedDate=format.format(calendar.getTime());
    return formattedDate;
}
```

To set date to calender instance after selecting date from date picker use it like below.

```
 DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            super.onDateSet(datePicker, year, month, day);
            Calender curDateInstance=Calender.getInstance();
            curDateInstance.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            curDateInstance.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            curDateInstance.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            txtPickUpDate.setText(DateUtils.getDate(curDateInstance));


        }
    };
```

Comment: yes you are right but in a case if i don't add it creates another problem . when i select any month it shows its previous month .

Comment: if I select Dec it is Showing Nov, if I am selecting Jan it works fine , When I select Feb it again selects Jan,

Comment: can you please post the code of your date selection.?

Comment: I have updated my question , i am working with using two dialogues. one for setting time other is for setting date. user first selects date then selects time.